# Prove that a Vector Orthogonal to an Orthonormal Basis is the Zero Vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Stuck in this proof.

Let W be an inner product space (with unspecified inner product,
$\langle\vec x, \vec y\rangle$), and with orthonormal basis $B = \{\vec w_1, \vec w_2, \ldots ,\vec w_n\}$.

Suppose that $\vec x$ is orthogonal to $\vec w_i$ for each 1 $\leq  i \leq n$.

Prove that $\vec x$ is the zero vector.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $x= \sum \langle x,w_i\rangle w_i$

Comment: honestly i've been staring at it for a while now don't really know where to start, I'm thinking something to do with the inner product of x and w1, w2, ...wn

Comment: Look at @RaziehNoori's hint. A property of a basis is that any vector in the vector space can be written as a unique linear combination of those basis vectors. What's more, if the basis is orthonormal those coefficients are the inner products $\langle x, w_i \rangle$. You may need to prove that last step. Then use what you know about all of those inner products from the hypothesis of the question

Comment: I think I got it. Appreciate you guys sending me in the right direction as opposed to just a straight out answer.

Comment: For a next challenge, try proving the result without assuming $B$ is orthonormal, just a basis (of inner product space $W$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{\mathbf{w_i}\}$ is a basis, any vector can be write as: 
$$
\mathbf v=\sum_i x_i \mathbf{w_i}
$$
now, from orthogonality, we have:
$$
\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf {w_i}=0 \quad \forall i \iff x_i=0 \quad \forall i
$$